# When will updates occur to the health status information?

Tags: tapkey

Recently I started logging the lock's healthstatus info. What exactly is the Timestamp of these objects?

I have lots of round timestamps (like 2022-05-20 12:00:00.000), but also arbitrary timestamps (like 2022-05-20 16:16:37.617). What exactly does this Timestamp mean? Is it when a lock is last opened?

Stan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you are talking about the healthStatuses property of a Boundlock documented here:
https://developers.tapkey.io/openapi/tapkey_access_management_web_api_v1/#/Bound%20Locks/BoundLocks_GetById

The timestamp means that this specific status was collected at this time. The collection can be triggered, depending from the type, from different events. E.g. during unlock, during start or internal timer.

If the event was an internal timer it can lead to a round timestamp, if the source was an external event, then the timestamp will of course not be round.